# Google mock invoke function with parameters

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
static bool helper(int a){
   // do something here
   return true;
}  

  class ProxyMock : public Proxy
    {
        public:
            MOCK_METHOD1(functionA, bool(
                int a
            ));
    };


TEST(xxx, xxx){
   ProxyMock mock;
   int a;
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, functionA(5)).WillOnce(testing::Invoke(helper(a));  
}
```

when functionA of mock object is called with parameter(5), I would like to invoke a static global function `helper` which takes in the parameter I want.
When compiling I got errors:
`'function' cannot be used as a function` in the `EXPECT_CALL` line. What is wrong?

Comment: Does the error message go into more detail?

Answer (score 3):

`Invoke` requires a functor. Functor is something that can be called (using `operator()`), e.g. a function pointer, a struct with overloaded `operator()` or a lambda.
Moreover, it requires the functor to match the mocked function regarding parameter types and return type (your `helper` fits that criteria), and it will always pass the arguments that mocked function received into that functor (which you don't want).

If you want to call a function with different argument, the simplest way would be to use `InvokeWithoutArgs` and a lambda:

```
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, functionA(5)).WillOnce(
        testing::InvokeWithoutArgs(
            [a](){return helper(a);}
        )
    );
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/5hqbfP8Eq)

Comment: `Invoke` doesn't require a functor. It can take any callable as google mock documentation defines. Also, you can directly pass the lambda even without `InvokeWithoutArgs`.

Comment: @Ari I agree, I meant "callable" instead of "functor", but since when you can pass lambda as `Action`? I mostly worked with Gtest 1.8 and I think it wasn't allowed back then.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass a callable of zero args that somehow has access to `a` to `WillOnce`. The easiest way to do so is using a lambda:

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(mock, functionA(5))
  .WillOnce([a]() { return helper(a); });
```

Note that `Invoke` passes the same argument that was passed to the function under test. So you should use it only if you want to pass `5` to `helper`:

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(mock, functionA(5))
   .WillOnce(testing::Invoke(helper));  // helper(5) will be called.
```

As an alternative you can use `InvokeWithoutArgs`, which acts like `Invoke` but does not pass any arguments to the callable that is its argument, but then again you should use something like a lambda capture to get access to `a`, so it's not necessary.

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/vqdxT86E4